# Count and Distinct SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct

I have a table of Books, that contains the following columns:

```
Book_Id   User_Id
001       1
002       2
001       1
004       2
005       3
006       3
007       2
008       2
009       1
```

**Where** :

> Book_Id - identifier of a book that a user read; User_Id - identifier
>   of a reader/user.

Let's assume that User1 read books three times, but 2 of them were same, so the user 1 read 2 distinct books (001 and 009). User 2 read 4 distinct books, while user 3 read 2 distinct books.
In overall, there are 2 users that read 2 distinct books, and 1 user that read 4 distinct books.
The output expected is as below:

```
Distinct_Books_Count --- User_Count
2                           2
4                           1
```

I tried the following:

> SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Book_Id), COUNT(User_Id) FROM Books GROUP BY
>   User_Id

But I receive the following table:

```
Distinct_Books_Count  User_Count
2                     3
4                     4
2                     2
```

So any alternative solution or changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I call this a "histogram of histograms" query.  You can do it using two `group by`s:

```
SELECT num_books, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT b.User_Id, COUNT(DISTINCT Book_Id) as num_books
      FROM Books b
      GROUP BY User_Id
     ) b
GROUP BY num_books
ORDER BY num_books;
```